# trace how much memory gets allocated per function

Tags: c

Is there a tool that allows me to trace how much memory is allocated per function? e.g. all memory allocated by `malloc` calls whenever my `add_node` function is called vs those in `queue_buffer`, etc. for the entire runtime of the program.

I'd like to profile where the bulk of memory is used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any program to do this offhand, but you can do this yourself. Just add something like this to some global header file:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void* __replacement_malloc(size_t bytes, const char* fn_name)
{
        printf("Function %s allocated %lu bytes\n", fn_name, bytes);
        return malloc(bytes);
}
#define malloc(x) __replacement_malloc(x, __func__)
#endif
```

Now when you compile with "DEBUG" defined, any calls to malloc() will be redirected.

Comment: well yes, I guess I'll have to maintain a list as well if I want to add up the sum of memory per function, I was just hoping something like that would already exist.